# Null Context in setUserVisibleHint

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-context

A message needs to be displayed to the user when a fragment in a ViewPager becomes visible. Currently the call is:

```
// Within a class that extends Fragment
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        MessageUtility.displayMessage(getContext());
    }
}
```

`MessageUtility.displayMessage()` opens an alert dialog with a message.

`Context` is required to display the message. However, the fragment is  not guaranteed to be attached by the time `setUserVisibleHint()` is called. Thus, the `Context` will be `null`, even though `isVisiableToUser == true` .

Checking `isVisibleToUser && isAttached()` works in theory, but `setUserVisibleHint()` is not provoked after `isAttached() == true`.

Is there some way to allow the call to `displayMessage()` to wait until the `Fragment` is attached?

Comment: See my edited Answer

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never ,I have a little hackish solution ,call  `setUserVisibleHint()` from `onActivityCreated()` method.

```
private boolean myIsVisibleToUser;

 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    myIsVisibleToUser=isVisibleToUser;
    if (isVisibleToUser && getActivity()!=null) {
          MessageUtility.displayMessage(getContext());    
        }
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    setUserVisibleHint(myIsVisibleToUser);

}
```

Comment: Your solution helped me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit different approach but more effective solution. Add a new `OnPageChangeListenr` to your `ViewPager`.

```
 yourPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                // Check if i == your fragment's position and display message        
                MessageUtility.displayMessage(getContext());
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: `setOnPageChangeListener` is deprecated, use `addOnPageChangeListener` instead