# Fragment setuserVisibleHint true but getActivity returns null

Tags: android, fragment, android-support-library

I've been doing some logic inside of a fragment's `setUserVisibleHint()` method. I was always checking if `isVisibleToUser` is true and then used `getActivity` to return the activity. This was working well (100% of the time) until I updated the support library to the latest(`support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0`). Now `getActivity` always returns null. Are there some changes to the support library that explain this behaviour?

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(false);

    if (isVisibleToUser) {
      getActivity() <- null
    }
```

Comment: @noev you can save the context value from **onAttach** function.

Comment: The question is why does this happen. It was working with the previous version of the support library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46557791/6478047 check this answer

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late to the party but maybe this can help someone. I solved this problem by creating a boolean member inside the fragment class. I used this then to determine whether or not I was able to successfully get the activity in the setUserVisibleHint method. If not, I execute the activity-related code in onAttach. See below.

```
public MyFragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    private boolean doInOnAttach = false;

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
        // if the fragment is visible
        if (true == visible) {
            // ... but the activity has not yet been initialized
            doInOnAttach = true;
        } else {
            myAction();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (true == doInOnAttach) {
            myAction();
            doInOnAttach = false;
        }
    }

    private void myAction() {
        // code to execute here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Google: "Prior to Android N there was a platform bug that could cause setUserVisibleHint to bring a fragment up to the started state before its FragmentTransaction had been committed. As some apps relied on this behavior, it is preserved for apps that declare a targetSdkVersion of 23 or lower."

So, there are two options:
 1. rebuild with targetSdkVersion < 24;
 2. modify the app according to new situation => use the context outside this callback, respectively in onAttach method or later on in the fragment lifecycle;

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser && (getActivity()!=null)) {
     getActivity();
    }
}
```

at first lunch getActivity() is Nullable